# System of equations with four unknown values

Tags: systems-of-equations

I'm French so don't hesitate to tell me if I'm unclear.

It's been 3 hours I'm stuck with the following problem:

Find all the solutions $(a, b, c, d)$ of the system of equations where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are real numbers

\begin{cases}
a+2023/a  &=2b \\
b+2023/b &=2c \\
c+2023/c &=2d \\
d+2023/d &=2a \\
\end{cases}

What I've tried so far with my limited mathematical skills:

- Gaussian elimination (failure, it seems that this method can't apply with this type of system)
- Cramer's rule (again a failure)

Can someone give me a hint in order to resolve this problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Techniques for linear systems don't apply because it's not a linear system.

Comment: Is there a specific method to resolve nonlinear systems?

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but can I have some tips or a hint to find the answer by myself ?

Answer (score 1):

Hints towards a solution:

- Note that $a, b, c, d$ have the same sign, so WLOG assume they are positive and we can apply $AM-GM$.
- Let $ a = \min (a, b, c, d)$. What can we say about $a$ from $ a + 2023 / a = 2b \geq 2a $?
- Show that $ b = a$.
- Hence conclude that $ a = b = c = d$.
- Thus, there are 2 solutions.